# What's the correct way to "flatten" data in mySQL from 3 dimensions to 2?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

**Labels**

**UserValues**

**Users**

Labels looks like this:

```
1|First Name
2|Last Name
3|Favorite Book
etc...
```

Users looks like this:

```
1|[phone_number]
2|[phone_number]
etc....
```

UserValues looks like this:

```
1|  [label_id_for_First_Name]  |John      |  [user_id]
2|  [label_id_for_Last_Name]   |Smith     |  [user_id]
3|  [label_id_for_Fav_Book]    |Moby Dick |  [user_id]
etc...
```

some users may have not filled in some fields (all are optional except for the phone number that is used as a primary key).

I'm stumped as to how I can write a query that would flatten this data to look like:

```
uid      |First_Name|Last_Name | Favorite_Book
[user_id]|John      |Smith     | Moby Dick //user has all fields filled in
[user_id]|Mary      | [null]   | Kite Runner //user didn't have a last name
```

The idea is that it would grow in column width for as many columns as there were labels associated with these particular users.

I'd like to select on the users and have 1 row per user with all the values going out to the right.

I can see how I can do this in several queries, but I was hoping to learn what the right way to do this is (maybe it IS to do it in several queries, but I suspect it's not).

TIA.

Comment: Check out EAV pattern(google it).

Comment: If your columns are _known_ and regular, why not include them in the table, instead of a separate values table? If your columns are _unknown_, how can you expect to get a reasonable table view dynamically without selecting the columns you want: couldn't there be thousands of columns?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Go teach yourself some [database normalization rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Your table schemas are not even in the 1NF. A single cell MUST have a single distinctive value belonging to a domain/column. The columns values belonging to different domains should not be mixed in the same column.

Comment: @Shef, it is precisely with normalization in mind that I have designed this.  The way this works is that I have a ton of users, but depending on what sort of user they are they do or do not have various fields associated with them.  Let's say there's a grand total of 1000 different labels, but any individual series of users (as they are grouped) will only have < 10. So, rather than have a table of users with 1000 columns (of which the vast majority are empty), I am handling it this way.  Ultimately, I don't HAVE to have a view of a single table as described above. I just thought it'd be nice

Comment: So, to be clear. A user signs up for a book club, they will have fields like "favorite_book" and "last_book_read" and "current_book" but only book club users will have these fields, someone who signs up via movie_club has whatever fields make sense there.  But they're all "users".  How would you normalize such a schema in a different way?

Comment: @Dani, yes... that looks exactly like what I'm doing (EAV).

Comment: @AndrewVit, by selecting specific users, I *would be selecting the columns I want because those users would all have the same bunch of columns. But sure, if you want to show me how to select based on specific labels, I'd be happy to get that advice as well.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel If these are different user _groups_ (or _classes_) and not random different fields, I would normalize it like this: 1. standard columns (first_name, last_name) go straight in the users table. 2. Split extra fields like "favorite_book" into a user_book_fields table that references back to users with a user_id foreign key. 3. Give users a type column so you know which users_x_fields table to join against it. As you admit, a join of all user types is not reasonable since you would have 1000 columns.

Comment: @Dani, EAV is an antipattern one that will make your DB slow.

Comment: Phone numbers make for **bad** PK's, I always fill in 06-12345678 as a phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a query using the current data and giving the result in the example this would be it:

**SQL coding horror**

```
SELECT 
  u.id as user_id
  , uvfirstname.value as firstname
  , uvlast_name.value as lastname
  , uvbook.value as book
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN uservalues uvfirstname 
       ON (uvfirstname.label_id =
             (SELECT l1.id FROM label l1 WHERE l1.name = 'First name')
           AND uvfirstname.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN uservalues uvlastname 
       ON (uvlastname.label_id = 
             (SELECT l2.id FROM label l2 WHERE l2.name = 'Last name')
           AND uvlastname.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN uservalues uvbook
       ON (uvbook.label_id = 
             (SELECT l3.id FROM label l3 WHERE l3.name = 'Fav book')
           AND uvbook.user_id = u.id)
```